# How to reduce the capacity of RedHawk Python library

Tags: redhawksdr

There are many RedHawk Python 2.7 libraries, and the capacity including Linux is getting bigger. Can RedHawk remove unnecessary Python 2.7 library module to reduce the capacity? Please let me know if there is a module available for deletion. Or, I am currently creating an image by compressing the whole system with gzip, but is there a more efficient compression method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is it you are trying to accomplish? If file size is that important it sounds like you are working on an embedded platform with limited disk space. Check out the features and work [here](https://github.com/Axios-Engineering/openembedded-hawk#features--options) on openembedded-hawk. It's been a while since I've updated it but you can have the entire REDHAWK framework built, with or without python, a REDHAWK Application, and the entire linux based OS all under 100 MiB. (Slightly more if you include python)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. As you can imagine, it's to fit in limited disk space. Our target size is 50MiB. Currently, 108MiB included embedded Linux. So we think about to reduce Python Libraries. I tried to execute your Yocto project files, however our RedHawk Version is 2.1 require  higher version of omniorb, omniorbpy(we use 4.2), so we changed your recipe files and compile. but there was no change in file size(still 108MiB).  Is there another way to reduce it?

Comment: 50MiB is really cutting it tight. Remember that you do not need python. If you are using the recipes from my project you'll notice that the redhawk package is divided up into redhawk and redhawk-python: https://github.com/Axios-Engineering/openembedded-hawk/blob/develop/recipes-redhawk/redhawk-core/redhawk-core_2.0.1.bb#L28-L46  If you have updated the recipes for redhawk 2.1 please consider submitting a pull request.

Comment: When I am using your YOCTO project on arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc. however the compile Error occuered in python-lxml, because of your project for x86 platform, Error message is 
"arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--should-not-have-used-/usr/bin/xml2-config"
Sorry to trouble you, could you tell me how to avoid it? Or Please tell me how to delete the above option.

Comment: I was finished compile your project. RedHawk Environment and Linux  sizes is 41.7MiB. I will port your project to our project on RedHawk V2.1. THank you so much!!

Comment: Glad it helped. Just to see if I could reduce it further I tried compiling the entire thing with -Os but it only saved a couple MiB, you could also get away with removing log4cxx however it may take some work redhawk should be able to compile with --disable-log4cxx but that will also only save you a couple more MiB.